# Rename feature classes in file geodatabase in bulk

Tags: arcpy, feature-class

I see may versions of this post but none quite get me to where I need to be.

I have 50,000 features classes in a file geodb.

They are a1_xxxxx_xx

I need to rename them all to a6_xxxxx_xxx

This is my code. Does not seem to quite work. Does create many a6 but a1 still remain when it completes.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import *

env.workspace = r"C:\IND_Rivers\New\Outputs\A3\a3_03.gdb"


fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

#attempts to replace feature classes with  "a1" with "a6" 
for fc in fcList:
    Rename_management(fc, fc.replace('a1','a6'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import *

env.workspace = r"C:\IND_Rivers\New\Outputs\A3\a3_03.gdb"
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

#attempts to replace feature classes with  "a1" with "a6" 
for fc in fcList:
    nn = 'a6' + fc[3:]
    arcpy.Rename_management(fc, nn)
```

Comment: Yeah, same result but it's worth a try to use the index instead of the replace function.

Comment: Are there datasets of the same name as the FCs? maybe the "FeatureClass" keyword is needed at the end?